# Attempting to save todo list items to local storage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have a pretty simple to do app that creates to dos and displays them to the screen. However, I wan't to save these to local storage so if someone leaves the page and returns, reloads the page, etc. the to do items remain.

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around how to use local storage though. I know relatively what I need to do, represented in pseudo code in my JavaScript document, but I can't seem to make it work. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

https://codepen.io/constequalsexcel/pen/GRJpzoE

```js
function addTodo() {
  let todoItem = document.createElement('li');
  todoItem.setAttribute('class', 'list-item');
  let text = document.getElementById('todo-input').value;
  if (text.length < 1) return;
  let textnode = document.createElement('span');
  textnode.innerText = text;
  // Create delete todo button
  let deleteButton = document.createElement('button');
  let deleteButtonX = document.createTextNode('X');
  deleteButton.appendChild(deleteButtonX);
  deleteButton.addEventListener('click', removeNode);
  // Create strike through radio input
  let StrikeThroughRadio = document.createElement('input');
  StrikeThroughRadio.setAttribute('id', 'checkbox-styles');
  StrikeThroughRadio.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox');
  StrikeThroughRadio.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    StrikeThroughRadio.checked ?
      e.target.nextElementSibling.classList.add('strike-text') :
      e.target.nextElementSibling.classList.remove('strike-text');
  });

  todoItem.appendChild(StrikeThroughRadio);
  todoItem.appendChild(textnode);
  todoItem.appendChild(deleteButton);
  enter code here

  document.getElementById('display').appendChild(todoItem);

// get saved todos from local storage and save it in a variable
// if saved todos variable is null then re-assign saved todoso variable equal to an empty array
// add current todo text to the saved todos array variable
// re-save saved todos into local storage (using the setItem() method)
    }
    function removeNode(e) {
      e.target.parentElement.remove();
    }
    `enter code here`

    function ClearInputOnSubmit() {
      document.getElementById('todo-input').value = '';
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html lang="en">

    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />

      <title>To-Do App</title>

      <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Mono&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    </head>

    <body>
      <h1 id="header">TO DO LIST</h1>
      <div class="main">
        <form class="container" class="needs-validation" novalidate>
          <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <input type="text" id="todo-input" class="form-control input-group shadow-lg" aria-describedby="button-addon2" required />
            <input type="button" value="Add ToDo" id="todo-button" id="button-addon2" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" onclick="addTodo(); ClearInputOnSubmit()" />
          </div>
        </form>
        <div class="todo-container">
          <h4 id="display" class="list-group">TODOS</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      <script src="scripts.js"></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Where is your code that tries to save to local storage? Just convert the list to JSON and use `localStorage.setItem()`

Comment: You need to create JavaScript objects to represent the todo items. You can't store DOM elements in local storage.

Comment: @Barmar: if you delegate the events, you can store/restore the innerHTML, which is enough to produce a working todo list app.

Answer (score 1):

The local storage runs as a way to store JavaScript objects. However, if the user clears their browser data, the objects will be lost.

`localStorage.setItem("storage", todoitem)`
`localStorage.getItem("storage")`

Looking at the need you have here, you may want to make a loop or array to store all of the `todoitem`s an user creates. If you are stuck on how you would do that, I can help. I actually started a [project](https://github.com/ForgivenNin/ls-loader) related to this issue.

[Here is a good reference if you are looking for more information.](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

Comment: Hey Forgiven, thanks for the reply. Concisely put, yes, I think my main sticking point is creating the array and getting my todos' stored in that array. From what I understand I can only store one value. So, I would need to keep updating this array and save it to local storage, then get it from local storage when needed?

Comment: sessionStorage is what does not persist. localStorage persists

Answer (score 0):

You can save only strings to the `localStorage`, and you can't `stringify` element nodes. But `innerHTML` gets the node as a string, so you can save it in the `localStorage`.

```
//to save the todo-list as a text in the local storage
localStorage.setItem('todoItem', todoItem.innerHTML);

//if you save single todo item at a time in the local storage,
//get the saved text(innerHTML) of the todo-list and append it to the container
todoItem = localStorage.getItem('todoItem');

document.getElementById('display').insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', todoItem);

//or if you save all of the todo-list at once, set the innerHTML of the container
document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = todoItem;
```

Answer (score 0):

When ever you in your code step, you ready to store/update data to the local storage, just call

```
localStorage.setItem("toItem", todoitem);
```

And when you want to read the stored item you can call the below method to get data

```
localStorage.getItem("todoItem");
```

Here is the document that that [document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Answer (score 0):

You could save each item to localStorage (not sessionStorage!!!) or you could batch them into a JSON object then store the entire thing as a string by first converting to as string JSON.stringify(your_json_object).

Scenario 1. save each item to local storage. one after another.

```
localStorage.setItem('item1', 'value1')
```

or

Scenario 2. build a JSON object first and save everything.

```
your_json_object = {item1: 'value1', item2: 'value2' ...};
localStorage.setItem(all_info: JSON.stringify(your_json_object));
```

Comment: remember to unserialize when reading by using 
    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('all_info'));